# Correct syntax to record mp3 from m3u url with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to record the stream from http://www.dradio.de/streaming/dlf.m3u with `ffmpeg`.

When accessing the file with the browser, a file gets downloaded with the following contents:

```
http://st01.dlf.de/dlf/01/128/mp3/stream.mp3
```

When I try to record the m3u url with:

`ffmpeg  -playlist 1 -i http://www.dradio.de/streaming/dlf.m3u  output.mp3`

I get an error message:
`http://www.dradio.de/streaming/dlf.m3u: Invalid data found when processing input`

The mp3 url itself can be downloaded with:

`ffmpeg  -i http://st01.dlf.de/dlf/01/128/mp3/stream.mp3  output.mp3`

As I do not want to process the contents of the m3u file (I expect it to be more complex in other cases):

**What is the correct syntax when I want to use the m3u url only?**

Comment: The syntax you are using is correct. This is the ancient "icecast" m3u format (without #EXTM3U header). ffmpeg seems to be into hls with the newer m3u8 format. Is using `mpv --stream-record=dlf.mp3 http://www.dradio.de/streaming/dlf.m3u` an option?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; it would be `mpv --record-file=dlf.mp3 http://www.dradio.de/streaming/dlf.m3u`, if I am not wrong. I am presently using `mplayer` for recording but I see shortcomings; especially regarding reconnecting after a connection loss. I thought that `ffmpeg` would be the most advanced tool for audio recording. But perhaps I am wrong?

Comment: In my opinion, `ffmpeg` is the most versatile tool. It is very rich in features, but some of them only cover basic use-cases. In this particular case, ffmpeg seems to be a less than ideal tool, since it has no support for the old m3u playlist format: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1199 For recording the actual stream.mp3, ffmpeg is as good as it gets.